# Stuck programming with arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, coordinates

For an assignment, we have to input an airplane wing thickness to length ratio, generate an x array of evenly spaced 20 points from 0 to 1, calculate the y coordinates (with the equation in my code below), and clearly display them back to the user. I've gotten started, but I am completely lost even after looking at other user questions about how to use arrays in Python. My question is: where do I go from here? Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy
import math

x = numpy.array([0, 1, 0.05])
y = 0
sqrt = x**(0.5)

tString = input("What is the thickness to length ratio (as a decimal)?")
t = float(tString)

y = (5*t)*((0.2969*sqrt) - (0.1260*x) - (0.3516*(x**2)) + (0.2843*(x**3)) - (0.1015*(x**5)))
```

Comment: So your question is...?

Comment: FYI you don't need semicolons at the end of lines in Python

Comment: @GPhilo Where do I go from here? I don't know what to use

Comment: "Where do I go from here?" is not a question this website can help you answer. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named 
["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). 
And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). 
You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @DavidG. Sometimes you do. For instance if you want to suppress output to the screen.

Comment: To get the proper values in the `x` array, you can use `numpy.linspace`

Comment: Write down each step in your own words before deciding how to implement that step in Python.  Choose as small steps as possible.  You have calculated `y`, what's next?  Did you try printing `y`?

Comment: @cdarke yes, but it gave me a list back with 3 different values?

Comment: That's because you are using three different values in `x`.

Comment: @PM2Ring thank you! that helped a lot and I now have 20 y-coordinate values.

Comment: The wording of this question is not suitable for this site. It's not a question but an invitation to a lengthy discussion. There's a reason why it's called a Q&A site and not a forum.

Comment: In case the OP misunderstood the assignment, or even in the case of a not well formulated assignment, I'd have a look at what is produced by `numpy.linspace(0, 1, 21)` ;) (that is `[0.00, 0.05, 0.10, ..., 0.95, 1.00]`)

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.linspace` and `numpy.vectorize`:

```
import numpy as np #1

x = np.linspace(0, 1, 20) #2
y = np.vectorize(
    lambda x, t: 5 * t * (.2969*x**.5 - .1260*x - .3516*x**2 + .2843*x**3 - .1015*x**5)
) #3

t = float(input("What is the thickness to length ratio (as a decimal)? ")) #4

print(y(x, t)) #5
```

1. Import `numpy` with the alias `np`. It is quite common among `numpy` users as you will probably have to write it lots of times. It is a convetion and saves you 3 letters per appearance.
2. Create a vector from 0 to 1 with 20 points equally spaced. See [`numpy.linspace`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) for further documentation.
3. Create a function that will be applied to each element of the input vector. It takes two arguments, x (vector with all the points where you want to apply the function) and t that can be an scalar. See [`numpy.vectorize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) for further documentation.
4. Ask for the length ratio in a single line, no need to store the string in a variable if you are only gonna convert it into a float.
5. Print the result.